# Is there a way to dump a table data (json or csv) from the Google SQL Cloud via a REAST API in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to locally dump a table data via a REST API from the Google Cloud SQL in python. I found a method with gcloud ([description here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#gcloud_1)) but I do not want to use this dependency. My question is if there is any way to download(on local storage) the data from a table without using gcloud or a proxy to the databse. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to export your data to a CSV file, you need to export it in a bucket.  [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#rest_1) you can find an example on how to do it using REST. At [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/export) other documentation, you can try this API to see what you should expect to get as result.

On the other hand, if you do not have configured the access to your local, you can take a look at [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip) that is another option if you do not want to use Cloud SQL Proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I was not clear enough, I am searching for a way to avoid the bucket storage and save it directly locally, without using the proxy method, but after some research I do not thing there is such a way.

Comment: Ohh in that case, it is not possible to do it without using GCS.  I think you can create a Feature Request  here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers choosing "Cloud SQL" as product. Only keep in mind that there are not ETAs or guarantees for FR implentation.